# Segmentation Fault(core dumped) C++11 Tree class

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm coding a bk-tree to use in my criptography work, but I'm having a segmentation fault(core dumped) with a simply set string method I created, I researched about what my error could be but unfortunately I couldn't find an answer.

I don't know if my code is working since I can't even test the insertions, here is the code(I had to put every file in this link since I don't have enough reputation to post more than 2 links and if I pasted everything here, would turn into a mess, sorry)
Code: http://pastebin.com/wDJH0A7a

Thank you

Comment: The text `setString` doesn't appear anywhere in the code at that link.

Comment: Its the method in main, setRoot, I just wrote "setString" because setRoot does that.

Comment: This is not a free debugging service. It is a site for questions about programming languages and pieces of code. It is possible to mould "help me fix my code" into a suitable question, but only by making it interesting and present a [minimal testcase](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You were instructed all about this by the system when you signed up.

Comment: It's not to debbug my entire code, I just sent it all because since I don't know what was causing setRoot to give a segmentation fault I sent the .cpp too, if  my class is all wrong or method Y is all wrong, I will fix it by myself, I just wanted to understand the setRoot problem, and one user here already showed the problem in a direct manner without having to debbug my code like you said.

Comment: @user3533910 Site policies claim for a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as _@Lightness_ already mentioned. You have to put in some efforts and minimize your code to show that behavior you're asking about and post it in your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to instantiate the `Node* root` variable before using it.
Create a constructor for the `BkTree` class and do `root = new Node();`

Comment: That was the problem, It's my first time using one object from class A inside class B so I thought when I created the object B it would create the A too, thank you very much

Comment: @perencia Well it's disputable, if it's really good behavior if other's mention _"This is not a free debugging service."_, which it actually isn't, and you're doing just the opposite. This merely just encourages other new users to try the same, instead of being helpful for anyone else.